# Show first 4 characters of field in a query

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is part of the existing query. I am trying to only show the first 4 characters of FIELD2, but its not working properly. Any ideas?

```
date(timestamp_format(char(FIELD1+19000000), 'YYYYMMDD'))  as XXXX,  
FIELD2 as XXXXX,
```

Basically, FIELD 2 is a time that is in format `TTTTTT`, so 10:00 is showing as 100000. I tried to do `(FIELD2-99000)` but it won't work for all cases so now I am just trying to show only the first 4 characters

Comment: Anyone? Really need to get this report completed. Would appreciate the help so much!

Comment: why are you fromatting the time in this way? on purpose?

Comment: i'm open to suggestions. i am new to crystal.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `int(left(char(FIELD2),4))` as XXXX

Answer (score 0):

If Field 2 is directly coming from database and you need only first 4 values then try as below.

Create a formula and write below code.

```
ToText(Field2)[4]
```

Comment: Hi Siva, I am using this in a query. Your suggestion did not work. Got the error failed to retreive data from the database.

Comment: don't use this in query instead use normal query and use this in crystal report formula.. this will work since `ToText` is a crystal function